# Using ID as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the text of the span with the class name "link" but i have problems.

```
<div id="item-0" class="box">
    .......
</div>
<div id="item-1" class="box">
    <p><strong>Link: </strong><span class="link">http://www.domain.com/list44/</span></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit" class="load-button2"></p>
</div>
<div id="item-2" class="box">
    .......
</div>


$(".load-button2").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.box').attr('id');
    alert(id);  // showing the right box ID
    var linkp = $(/*** what should i put here? ***/ "#" + id + " .link").text;
});
```

Comment: *What* problems exactly?

Comment: `var linkp = $("#" + id + " .link").text();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
$(".load-button2").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.box').attr('id');
    alert(id);  // showing the right box ID
    var linkp = $("#" + id).find(".link").text();
});
```

Although, a more elegant solution would be:

```
$(".load-button2").click(function(){
    var linkp = $(this).closest('.box').find(".link").text();
});
```

Comment: How about just `$(this).closest('.box').find('.link').text()` ?  Doesn't seem like there's any need to re-locate the box.

Comment: Ha ha, yeah, I was just updating to say that :)

Comment: @Pointy: Just noticed my answer and your comment are exactly the same (and posted 2 seconds apart).

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code:

```
$(".load-button2").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).closest('.box').find('.link').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".load-button2").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.box').attr('id');
    alert(id);  // showing the right box ID
    //var linkp = $(what should i put here / "#" + id = " .link").text;
    var linkp = $("#"+id).find(".link").text;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative so you don't have to do another full DOM traversal (since you already get the container).

```
$(".load-button2").click(function(){
    var container = $(this).closest('.box');
    var id = container.attr('id');
    alert(id);  // showing the right box ID
    var linkp = container.find('.link').text();
    alert(linkp);
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/9L8gW/).